# Google sheets script - how to concate variable?

Tags: variables, google-sheets

I have this code:

```
function _1() {
var aa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = aa.getSheets()[0];
var cell = sheet.getRange("k1");
var cell = sheet.getvalue("a" + cell + ")");
};
```

In cell k1 there is a number (variable). I want to use this cell in my function, but its not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You entire code is correct, except last line:

```
var cell = sheet.getvalue("a" + cell + ")")
```

You don't need to import range value again in your getValue and it will cause error, and below is the correct execution by convert value to string (*remove ; after } ):

```
function test_1() {
var aa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = aa.getSheets()[0];
var cell = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
cell = cell.toString() + "a"
Logger.log(cell);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*[getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()) does not take any input parameter. Join the strings later*

### Solution

I attach you a function that reads the number in B2 (X) and writes a string in AX.

```
function test_1() {
var aa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = aa.getSheets()[0];
var B2 = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
var cell = "A" + B2.toString()
sheet.getRange(cell).setValue('test')
}
```

### References

- [Range.getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())
- [Range.setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)